# Pushing to a random veiwcontroller in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, random, storyboard

**Part 1**

Alright, I am pretty new to this and am making a new app. However I am having trouble making my have a random effect. What I want is for on one veiwcontroller I have a button, and when pressed it pushes you to one of 100 other view controllers but randomly, while using storyboards. Right now i have 100 veiwcontrollers on a storybaord and 1 of them being home, and has a start button on it, I want it so when you press the start button it will randomly go to one of the other 100 veiwcontrollers. Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I said I am new to this. Thanks in advanced!

**Part 2**

Okay its starting to make sense now, but like I said I'm new to this. I have provided a image of a test code that I made to see if this works, however when I run this and press the button it just freezes.
My .m file:

```
#import "StartPage.h"
#import "ViewController1.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "ViewController3.h"
#import "ViewController4.h"

@interface StartPage ()

@end

@implementation StartPage

- (IBAction)randomButton
{
NSArray *viewControllerList; {
    NSString *ViewController1 = ViewController1;
     NSString *ViewController2 = ViewController2;
     NSString *ViewController3 = ViewController3;
     NSString *ViewController4 = ViewController4;

}
NSString *randomViewControllerClassName = viewControllerList[arc4random() % 99];
UIViewController *randomVC = [[NSClassFromString(randomViewControllerClassName) alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:randomVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

My .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StartPage : UIViewController

- (IBAction) randomButton;

@end
```

And my storyboard has a navigation controller and 5 other view controllers, and on the first view controller I have a button, and that is the "randomButton" in my .h and .m, and that is segue to viewcontroller1, and the rest are not segued but have their respective veiwcontroller class. So I am stuck, I really appreciate you helping me and would glady pay back the favour. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are probably endless ways of doing this, some of which will be better or worse depending on the rest of your app.

A simple way would be to create an array of view controller class names, then use a random number generator to pick an index at random, then instantiate and load the class.

.m

```
@interface StartPage()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *viewControllerList;
@end

@implementation StartPage

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.viewControllerList = [@"BobViewController", @"TomViewController", ..., @"OneHundrethViewController"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)buttonTapped {
    NSString *randomViewControllerClassName = viewControllerList[arc4random() % 99];
    UIViewController *randomVC = [[NSClassFromString(randomViewControllerClassName) alloc] init]
    [self presentViewController:randomVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help however I have some questions, I'm not sure how to populate the veiwcontrollerList and also how would I connect this to my button? Would I put it in the buttons method? This would also mean I would have to create a class for every viewcontroller, yes? Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, you would need to create a class for every view controller. How could you have 100 view controllers to select at random without creating the view controllers? You would populate your `viewControllerList` once and then in the an `IBAction` associated with your button you'd call the rest of the code. As for how to populate the list... however you want to. It would just be a list of strings for all your view controller names. You hard code it, read it from a file, pull it from a plist or download it from the internet. Whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I have updated my question to show part two (just above) so I could show you my code, can you provide me with any help please. Greatly appreciated. @DBD